# How to mark class' properties' data annotation not to get error if there is not in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have base class :

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public int AutoId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }



    // NOT REQUIRED // START

    public Guid? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedComputerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedIP { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedComputerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedIP { get; set; }

    // NOT REQUIRED // END

}
```

I have classes that get inheritance by `BaseEntity`.

In my database, some table has not to have these properties. ( NOT REQUIRED SECTION PROPERTIES )

If I don't put into table these properties in database, I got error naturally when project is started.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SqlException: Invalid column name 'CreatedByUserId'.
>
> Invalid column name 'CreatedComputerName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'CreatedDate'.
>
> Invalid column name 'CreatedIP'.
>
> Invalid column name 'ModifiedByUserId'.
>
> Invalid column name 'ModifiedComputerName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'ModifiedDate'.
>
> Invalid column name 'ModifiedIP'.

How can I mark these properties as optional.

Maybe there is this field in database, maybe there is not.

Comment: If you don't want that properties, just don't include them in your **domain** models. You can place them inside another classes that you didn't introduce a `DbContext` for them in your `DataContext` class.

Comment: I have to use this `BaseEntity` class. But some tables have these fields, some tables havent. it has be dynamic. So i have to mark these fields `This field is not required.` or something like this.

Comment: When a class inherits from another class it inherits all members of the base class. This is how inheritance works.

Comment: You didn't use any kind of `DataAnnotations` in you code. The code you've shown has nothing to do with `DataAnnotations`.

Comment: I want to use DataAnnotation to mark these field as not required. And i ask this DataAnnotation or someting like this ?

Comment: You can mark a property by `[Required]` and then it *tells EF that a particular property is required.* So simply if you **don't** use this attribute it **isn't required**.

Comment: It gives me error which i've written in my post when i dont use any annotation. I have to use anything to mark'em not to get error, i guess. Am i wrong?

Comment: OK. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude that properties from you base class and move them to the derived class and then use the [`[NotMapped]`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) as an attribute of the derived class. So even if you map the `BaseEntity` class to the table, the `Discriminator` columns will not be created because the derived class has marked as `[NotMapped]`:

```
[NotMapped]
class NotRequired : BaseEntity
{
    // NOT REQUIRED // START

    public Guid? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedComputerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedIP { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedComputerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedIP { get; set; }

   // NOT REQUIRED // END
}
```

And if you still want to keep this properties in your base class you can apply `NotMapped` attribute to a property which you don't want to create a column in a database table for:

```
[NotMapped]
public string CreatedComputerName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

@S.Akbari

This fluent api gives me what i want.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>(opt =>
        {
            opt.ToTable("Parameter");
            opt.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            opt.Property(x => x.AutoId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            opt.HasAlternateKey(x => x.AutoId);

            opt.Ignore("CreatedByUserId");
            opt.Ignore("CreatedComputerName");
            opt.Ignore("CreatedIP");
            opt.Ignore("ModifiedByUserId");
            opt.Ignore("ModifiedComputerName");
            opt.Ignore("ModifiedDate");
            opt.Ignore("ModifiedIP");
        });
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. You can  also apply `NotMapped` attribute to a property which you don't want to create a column in a database table for. Also by using `NotMapped` you have used `DataAnnotation` that you were looking for.

Comment: In your case, it is not dynamic. In my case, I can ignore fields easily what i don't want to map. Because some classes have only `CreatedDate`, others have `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate` etc... And, not necessary to create extra class to unmap them.

Comment: I tried it, when I mark it `NotMapped`, It never has been mapped even there is field in database.